# Navigation header inflating twice on programmatically setting textview

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set up Name and email textview in navigation header in default Navigation Activity using `inflateHeaderView`. However, this is causing the header to inflate twice (one on the another). Also, email is not appearing in the navigation header programmatically. I have used same method for name textview and it works fine. Here is my "HomeScreen.java" code:

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("ThirdEye");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //programmatically setting navigation header name and email:
        View navheaderView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home_screen);
        TextView userName = (TextView) navheaderView.findViewById(R.id.navheader_name);
        TextView userEmail = (TextView) navheaderView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
        String user_name = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
        String user_email = sharedPreferences.getString("user_email","");
        userName.setText(user_name);
        userEmail.setText(user_email);

    }
```

Any helps??

Comment: post your nav_view xml code please..

Comment: are u sure that your user_email is not empty

Comment: @Tanimreja I have been able to remove the duplicity of navigation header by removing "app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home_screen" from nav view xml. I guess I was inflating it twice, both in xml as well as in java.....but email is still not working..user_email gets value from edittext view in another activity..

Comment: if you added that header view in xml then dont need to inflate it again in java code... make sure that u are getting value of user_email from shardpreference .... using debug or Log.e..

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
View navheaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below. It works for me.

```
View navheaderView =  navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home_screen);
navigationView.addHeaderView(navheaderView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

View navheaderView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_home_screen, false);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).